# SXA Value cannot be null. Parameter name: siteInfo

Tags: sxa, sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

I have installed sitecore commerce on my local machine.I have also added Tenant and SXA Site.

Everything worked fine until i encountered with an issue when i click on the site, i am getting the following error when i click on the site node.

Error 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: siteInfo

[image]

Comment: What is your stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this, Verify following are set up correctly

1. Valid SXA licence is present
2. Make sure the host name in /sitecore/content/Sitecore/Storefront/Settings/Site Grouping/Storefront is correctly configured to the web site you are browsing the sitecore in.
3. Make sure the template of the home item is inheriting the home page configuration template.
   [image]

Comment: Yes, In my case it was wrong licence file.I have replaced it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error comes only in few scenarios like below.

1. Expired/Corrupted/Wrong Sitecore License.
2. Wrong configurations in Sitecore SXA site-manager and site grouping.
3. If you patch something wrong in SiteDefinition.config file.
4. Or Site order is wrong in Multisite settings.