# SXA Media Link Component - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: name in Experience Editor

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, experience-editor

I am working with `SXA` `Sitecore 10` where I used Media Link Component to attach a file.

Everything is working fine except attaching a file in Experience Editor.

I always get

> Value cannot be null. Parameter: name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/22030/sxa-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-siteinfo